# passing edittext parameter

Tags: android, android-edittext

I tried to call an method from one class to an activity class but im having nullpointer exception on the edittext.

// this is the method i created in method class

```
public void getEditTextValue(EditText edittext, int resources, String  DataValue , String vEditTextValue) {

            methods md = new methods();
            edittext = (EditText) findViewById(resources);
            vEditTextValue = edittext.getText().toString();
            md.editorSharePreferences(this, DataValue, vEditTextValue);
        }
```

// i call this method in the main activity class, i declare a public EditText edittext at the beginning of the class

```
public EditText edittext;

methods md = new methods();

md.getEditTextValue(currentEmployerMonth, R.id.etTimeWithYourCurrentEmployerMonths, "dCurrentEmployerMonth", vCurrentEmployerMonth);
```

Comment: Your method declaration and the call you make on it have differing numbers of parameters (4 and 5). Which one of those is incorrect?

Comment: did u watch my answer ?

Comment: yea i did, erm im not passing the edittext value from one class to another. im declaring an edittext in another class

Answer (score 1):

send edit text value as String and get again in other activity and assign where you want to assign the value of edittext

function (edittext.tostring());